# Use of PTPd on RedHat/CentOS

Tags: linux, timestamp, redhat, centos6, ptpd

I need to create a reliable and accurate synchronization between two CentOS 6 machines connected through a direct Ethernet connection.

I've seen that on Linux several implementation of [the IEEE 1588 Precision Time Protocol (PTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_Time_Protocol) exist:

- [PTPd](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ptpd/):

  - Apparently, this is the original implentation
  - Source code available on [GitHub](http://www.github.com/ptpd/ptpd) (appparently, <s>still maintained</s> almost unmaintained)
- [PTPd2](http://ptpd2.sourceforge.net):

  - A new version meant to supersede the previous implementation
  - Apparently unmaintained
  - For CentOS 6, available only in the EPEL repositories
- [PTPv2d](http://code.google.com/p/ptpv2d):

  - A further implementation
  - Unmaintained as well
- [linuxptp](http://linuxptp.sourceforge.net):

  - A specific implementation for Linux
  - Maintained
  - Available on the CentOS repositories
  - Suggested by the RedHat documentation for both [RedHat 6](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-Configuring_PTP_Using_ptp4l.html) and [RedHat 7](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Using_PTP.html)

My questions follow:

- Why does the RedHat documentation [suggest the use of linuxptp](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-Installing_PTP.html) for RedHat 6 (based on Linux kernel 2.6) despite [the linuxptp documentation says that a Linux kernel version 3.0 or newer is needed](http://linuxptp.sourceforge.net/) ?
- Which are differences between PTPd2 and Linuxptp in terms of reliability and timing accuracy ?
- Which one should I prefer on CentOS 6 and on CentOS 7, respectively ?
- Why either PTPd2 and Linuxptp do not synchronize immediately and often need me to start/stop the service several times or manually change system time through `date` to make the machine synchronize ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linuxptp works on RH6 thanks to RedHat backporting PTP support, as explained [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s1-installing_ptp). Indeed, it is the only choice, as the other packages have not been  maintained.